# when / if - in conditionals

Tags: conditionals

If I say:

> 1 I will play chess with you when you call me.

it will mean:

> 2 I will play chess with you if you call me.

But would there be any difference between:

> 3 I will play chess with you when I have lunch.

it will mean:

> 4 I will play chess with you if I have lunch.

Does 3 mean "I will play chess with you while having lunch?"

Does 4 mean "I will play chess with you after I have had lunch?"

Comment: Your first assertion is mistaken (#1 does ***not*** mean the same as #2). If you say ***when***, the implication is that situation ***will*** arise. When you say ***if***, the implication is that situation ***might*** arise (or it ***might not*** - that's why it's called a "conditional"). And ***when I have lunch*** means exactly that - ***while*** I'm lunching. The ***if*** version says nothing about ***when*** you'll play - only that you ***will*** at some point, ***if*** the condition is fulfilled.

Comment: So 3 and 4 mean different things?

Comment: Obviously. #3 implies I ***will*** have lunch, and ***at that time*** (during, not before or after) I will play chess. But #4 explicitly states that I'll only play ***if*** I have lunch, which implies ***I might not have lunch at all***.

Comment: OK. Then 1 should mean "I will play chess with you while you are calling me."?

Comment: Your example #1 is slightly unusual. You're probably not thinking about playing chess over the phone, so it ***must*** imply ***after*** you call, not ***during*** the call. But that's more because of real-world practical considerations than actual language (both the phrasing *and* the real-world meaning are a bit "unusual", so it's not a useful example for people learning English).

Comment: OK, but is 1 grammatically correct?

Comment: I think everything you've written here is "grammatically correct". But much of it is useless, because it's not what native Anglophones would say in the first place, so neither the grammaticality or the meaning is particularly worth spending time on.

Answer (score 2):

The main differene between "when" and "if" is not "during/after" but an implied difference in certainty about if the hypothetical will become true.

So 1,2 are different in meaning.  1 expresses the idea that "you are certain to call me, and at that time I will play chess".  2. expresses the idea "You might call me or you might not, but in the case that you do call me, on that condition (but not necessarily at that time) I will play chess".  In 2, it could mean "I'll play chess at some later time"

The same difference exists between 3, and 4.

Answer (score -2):

The main point is whether a **when-cluase** conveys an action which takes place **during** the time when the action in the main clause is taking place, or it conveys an action taking place **after** the main clause's action is fulfilled. I think it depends on whether the verb in the when-clause is durative or punctual. If it's durative then it means DURING, if it's punctual, it means AFTER.

> I will play chess with you when you arrive.
>
> I will play chess with you when you cook a cake.

Comment: Neither of those sentences is idiomatic. _Arrive_ can't take a name or personal pronoun as an object, and we _bake_ cakes.

Comment: I would like those who downvoted to come forward and refute my point.

Comment: Kate, but your arguments are completely beyond the point I make in my post. All the mistakes you point out have nothing to do with the difference between PUNCTUAL/DURATIVE verbs.

Comment: I didn't say they had anything to do with it, just that they were not valid English sentences. _While you are baking a cake_ would be more natural (if indeed it's possible to play chess and bake at the same time!)